# TFS Lock Work Items in State

Tags: tfs, workitem

Once work items in a particular workflow reach a "tested/resolved" end state, I don't want them to be editable.  I could enter Field restrictions on the end state for every field that exists, but that's a pain and doesn't easily support the addition of future fields.  Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Alas, I don't think there is an "out of the box" way to do this except for using the "when" clause on each of the fields or adding it to the state transitions to "tested/resolved" (as you have indicated).

Comment: Vaccano - if you enter this as an answer I'll accept it.  Nobody else seems to know how to do it either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, I don't think there is an "out of the box" way to do this except for using the "when" clause on each of the fields or adding it to the state transitions to "tested/resolved" (as you have indicated).